# How to replace string with cross after 2 characters of a string in php?

Tags: php, jquery

i have a email like this

```
$email="yourname@email.com";
$mob="9000000001";
```

how to get the desired output in php like

```
email=youxxxx@gmail.com
mob=900xxxxxx01
```

any help appreciated

Comment: Get first part of string, add `xxxx`, get last part of string. Concatenate.

Comment: http://php.net/substr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function obfuscate($data) {
    // for email addresses: do not obfuscate beyond at symbol
    $clear = strpos($data, "@");
    // for non-emails addresses: keep last two characters clear
    if ($clear === false) $clear = max(0, strlen($data)-2);
    // start hiding from 3rd character onwards, or earlier in some exceptional cases:
    $hide = max(0, min($clear-1, 3));
    return substr($data, 0, $hide) .
           str_repeat("x", $clear - $hide) . 
           substr($data, $clear);
}

echo obfuscate("yourname@email.com"); // youxxxxx@email.com
echo obfuscate("9000000001");         // 900xxxxx01
```

There are some safeguards (using *min* and *max* functions) in the code for not producing bad results in extreme cases, like when the email is very short *"a@abc.com"* or the number only has 3 digits.